# "--" is not permitted within comments: why this error occurs

Tags: xml, xml-comments

I have used 1 comment inside an xml document.

**<!-- Coded by ABC on 2012-02-02 for Version v3 -->**

It is working fine on my system.
But when I have deployed my software to the server, it is giving error on this line.

**"--" is not permitted within comments.**

How to resolve this problem?

Please tell me if any information I left to provide you...since I dont know much about xml.
I built it based on some examples.

Comment: Hi Valamas, I have not used CDATA inside it. Actually I work for a company, the source code they have given me is having plain xml. They didn't used it like a DTD. The xml is like shown below:            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="paymentplan"
             expand="false">
    <param name="paymentplan_limit"
           value="15"
           type="String" />
  </parameter></parameters>